# multiple functions in javascript fail when in one file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been working on a webpage with some simple form validation and submit using javascript functions and ajax.  I have written a function that validates a form and then submits it to another php page.  I have then created a second form and validating/submitting javascript function.  Both work separately, so I don't think it is my functions that are wrong, however when I try to put them into one js file to call them, only one of the functions works.  I can remove the other re-upload it and it calls fine.  I would appreciate it if someone could spot what I am doing wrong.

```
$(function () {
    $('.error').hide();
});

function publication(){
    $('.error').hide();
        var title = $("input#title").val();
            if (title == "") {
                $("label#title_error").show();
                $("label#title_error").css("color", "red");
                $("input#title").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var author = $("input#author").val();
            if (author == "") {
                $("label#author_error").show();
                $("label#author_error").css("color", "red");
                $("input#author").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var publisher = $("input#publisher").val();
            if (publisher == "") {
                $("label#publisher_error").show();
                $("label#publisher_error").css("color", "red");
                $("input#publisher").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var avail = $("input#avail").val();
            if (avail == "") {
                $("label#avail_error").show();
                $("label#avail_error").css("color", "red");
                $("input#avail").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var info = $("textarea#info").val();
            if (info == "") {
                $("label#info_error").show();
                $("label#info_error").css("color", "red");
                $("textarea#info").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var webaddr = $("input#webaddr").val();
        var YYYY = $("input#YYYY").val();
        var img = $("input#img").val();
    var dataString = 'title='+ title + '&author=' + author + '&publisher=' + publisher + '&avail=' + avail + '&info=' + info + '&YYYY=' + YYYY + '&webaddr=' + webaddr + '&img=' + img;
        //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/add_publication.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#event_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Publication Added</h2>")
            .append("<p>The publication has been added to the database.</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function events(){
    $('.error').hide();
        var eventname = $("input#eventname").val();
            if (eventname == "") {
                $("label#event_error").show();
                $("label#event_error").css("color", "red");
                $("input#eventname").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var venue = $("input#venue").val();
            if (venue == "") {
                $("label#venue_error").show();
                $("label#venue_error").css("color", "red");
                $("input#venue").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var info = $("textarea#info").val();
            if (info == "") {
                $("label#info_error").show();
                $("label#info_error").css("color", "red");
                $("textarea#info").focus();
                return false;
            }
        var webaddr = $("input#webaddr").val();
        var DD = $("input#DD").val();
        var MM = $("input#MM").val();
        var YYYY = $("input#YYYY").val();
        var DD2 = $("input#DD2").val();
        var MM2 = $("input#MM2").val();
        var YYYY2 = $("input#YYYY2").val();
        var img = $("input#img").val();
    var dataString = 'eventname='+ eventname + '&venue=' + venue + '&info=' + info + '&webaddr=' + webaddr + '&DD=' + DD + '&MM=' + MM + '&YYYY=' + YYYY + '&DD2=' + DD2 + '&MM2=' + MM2 + '&YYYY2=' + YYYY2 + '&img=' + img;
        //alert (eventString);return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/add_event.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#event_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Event Added</h2>")
            .append("<p>The event has been added to the database.</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The `publication` and `events` functions are called via `click` handlers in the HTML (here it's `publication`):

```
<table width="100%" id="publication">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">Title:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="50" />
        </td>
        <td width="30%">
            <label class="error" for="title" id="title_error">This field is required.</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Author:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="author" type="text" id="author" size="50" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="error" for="author" id="author_error">This field is required.</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Publisher:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="publisher" type="text" id="publisher" size="50" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="error" for="publisher" id="publisher_error">This field is required.</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Publication Year:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="YYYY" type="text" id="YYYY" size="4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Website:</td>
        <td>http://
            <input name="webaddr" type="text" id="webaddr" size="50" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Availability:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="avail" type="text" id="avail" size="30" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="error" for="avail" id="avail_error">This field is required.</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Publication Information:</td>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="info" id="info"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="error" for="info" id="info_error">This field is required.</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image Name:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="img" type="text" id="img" size="50" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="pubs_btn" value="Add" onclick="publication()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can hopefully see there are three things happening here.  1: all error messages are being hidden on page load, second and third are my two functions - publication and events.  I have several verified fields which get given a rec error message if they are blank.  I am then sending all the variables into a string to be submitted via ajax to a php file to insert them into my sql database.

I could be missing something as simple as a semi-colon somewhere - but as I have never written multiple functions in one file I haven't worked that out.

Comment: Have you remembered the change the src href in the "other" HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
var eventString = 'eventname='+ eventname + '&venue=' + venue + '&info=' + info '&webaddr' + webaddr + '&DD' + DD + '&MM' + MM + '&YYYY' + YYYY + '&DD2' + DD2 + '&MM2' + MM2 + '&YYYY2' + YYYY2 + '&img' + img;
// Here ------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

This prevents your JavaScript from being correctly parsed, thereby preventing your code from being run when the click occurs.

---

Your web browser was telling you about this: If you open your web console or developer tools, you'll see the error listed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this error out, when I retyped the eventString to check for errors I missed the + out and the = in all headers after info.

Comment: This has now been solved.  Many Thanks for your help